# Could not execute method of the activity with dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm receiving this error without much informations

```
E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4214)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5047)
        at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:9301)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2695)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8683)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1503)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2405)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1738)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:130)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:133)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2814)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2320)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4088)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4038)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3600)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3653)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3736)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3793)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3600)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3653)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3600)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3653)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3769)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3930)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2206)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2183)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5597)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     Caused by: java.l
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.app, PID: 32686
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4214)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5047)
        at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:9301)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2695)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8683)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1503)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1508)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2405)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1738)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:130)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:133)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2814)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2320)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4088)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4038)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3600)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3653)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3736)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3793)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3600)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3653)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3600)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3653)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3769)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3930)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2206)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2183)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5597)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
        at com.android.int
I/AndroidRuntime: To Report FATAL to activityManagerService
I/AndroidRuntime: Finished reporting FATAL to activityManagerService
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32686 SIG: 9
Process 32686 terminated.
```

This is my MainActivity code:

```
private CustomDialog dialog = null;
private String currentName = "Initial tile";

public void onClick(View view) { //Method called on press of button
    if(dialog == null){
        dialog = new CustomDialog(this);
    }
    dialog.setTitle(currentName);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Custom dialog code:

```
private Activity activity;
private TextView tv_1;
private String title = "No title";
private int updateIndex = 0;

public CustomDialog(Activity activity){
    super(activity, R.style.MyStyle);
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setCancelable(false);
    setContentView(R.layout.customDialog);
    tv_1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    updateIndex = 0;
    tv_1.setText(updateIndex + " " + title);
    activity.registerReceiver(updateTitle, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

private BroadcastReceiver updateTitle = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateIndex++;
        tv_1.setText(updateIndex + " " + title);
    }
};

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    activity.unregisterReceiver(updateTitle);
    dismiss();
}
```

The error isn't helping because it's not telling me where the error is but I'm assuming it's in the setText method.

I already tried putting the setText methods inside activity.runOnUiThread but I still get the same error.

What does "Caused by: java.l" mean?